# trying to send BCC field to php mailer

Tags: php, linux, centos

I have this code that was given to me by someone like 5 yrs ago, it works good, but now I need to send a fixed bcc field.  I have no idea what I am doing, can some one please helpo me?

… some of the code has been sniped out.. (mostly user email server password, port...)

foreach($users as $u){

```
            echo "Procesando...\n";
            print_r($u);
            flush();
            $msg="Nombre:".$u->name."<br/>";
            $msg.="Email:".$u->email."<br/>";
            $msg.="Fecha:".$u->date."<br/>";
            $mail=new PHPMailer();
            //indico a la clase que use SMTP
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            //permite modo debug para ver mensajes de las cosas que van ocurriendo
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
            //Debo de hacer autenticación SMTP
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
            //indico el servidor de Gmail para SMTP
            $mail->Host = SMTP_SERVER;
            //indico el puerto que usa Gmail
            $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;
            //indico un usuario / clave de un usuario de gmail
            $mail->Username = SMTP_USER;
            $mail->Password = SMTP_PASS;

            $mail->AddReplyTo(REPLY_EMAIL,REPLY_NAME);
            $mail->AddCC(SMTP_USER);
            $mail->Subject = "Nuevo mensaje de contacto";
            $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
            $mail->FromName = REPLY_NAME;
            //indico destinatario
            $mail->AddAddress($u->email, $u->name);
            $x=$mail->Send();
            print_r($x);
            //exit;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using PHPMailer which documentation is located at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

If you look at the example, you can see the function to add BCC

`$mail->addBCC('bcc@exmaple.com');`

You can use a variable

`$bcc = "bcc@exmaple.com";
$mail->addBCC($bcc);`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was was I was looing for!!